# SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. --->

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I am using ksop2 dependency ***(compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0')***for hitting soap web service , but getting below exception.

**Exception -** 
 *SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> wwdjwdwdewwes' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@3303970c*

**JAVA CODE**

```
      private final SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapObject request) {
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.implicitTypes = true;
            envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            return envelope;
        }

        private final HttpTransportSE getHttpTransportSE() {
            HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Proxy.NO_PROXY,MAIN_REQUEST_URL,60000);
            ht.debug = true;

            return ht;
        }

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);
      HttpTransportSE ht = getHttpTransportSE();

       ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
       // testHttpResponse(ht);
        received = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are sending some thing null in `envelope`.

```
if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
    SoapFault soapFault = (SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn;
    String requestStr = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;

} else {
    SoapObject soapObject = ((SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn);
    String requestStr = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
}
```

check your request in `requestStr` and comment `received = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();`

Comment: Yes SoapObject innerText is null

Comment: for now add dummy value in innerText and check its working or not

Comment: Now getting error "Server was unable to process request. ---> wwdjwdwdewwes"

Comment: ht.call(MAIN_REQUEST_URL  + "/"+SOAP_ACTION, envelope); or check SOAP_ACTION

Comment: not working - SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://4.......asmx/http://tempuri.org/readUser.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@3307c43c

Comment: add MAIN_REQUEST_URL and  SOAP_ACTION

Comment: Not working after adding this getting exception "faultcode: 'soap:Client' faultstring: 'Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: "

Comment: add MAIN_REQUEST_URL and SOAP_ACTION  here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130779/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-pravin).